# Sqlite: won't show up multiple results

Tags: sqlite, select

I've got two tables 1. List of continents 2. Contries belonging to each of 6 continents. In my app I want to show up in table view continent name and countries belonging to this continent. My current select:

```
SELECT cont.continentID,cont.continentName,cont.continentImage,(select contr.countryName   from countries as contr where contr.relativeToContinent=cont.continentID) as 'hash'\
    FROM Continents as cont
```

I frankly to say, was expecting to see the full list of countries because select contr.countryName   from countries as contr where contr.relativeToContinent=cont.continentID select, yes, retrieves the full list, but when all the selects are combined together I am getting only first country from list. How to solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

give us a database example (just export all the database with `sqlite3 db.sqlite .dump`) then we can try it out ourselves. i think it could be done with join or something.